# Can Bash I/O redirection work within a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

In Bash, I want to compare the fields of 2 different CSVs (field 2 of file1 and field 3 of file2):

```
diff <(cut -d, -f2 file1) <(cut -d, -f3 file2)
```

I tried to implement this more generally in Ruby:

```
def identical_files?(file1, field1, file2, field2)                                                                                                              
  %x{diff <(cut -d, -f#{field1} #{file1}) <(cut -d, -f#{field2} #{file2})}.blank?                                   
end
```

Printing the output of the `%x{}` block, I see `sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`.  Does I/O redirection not work when running shell commands within Ruby?  Is this because it's only supported by bash but not sh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn’t work because, as the error you’re getting indicates, Ruby shells out to sh, not Bash. And, of course, sh does not support that syntax.

You can instead call Bash explicitly:

```
`bash -c 'cat <(echo foo)'`  #=> "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this because it's only supported by bash but not sh?

Yes.

Process substitution is not supported by sh, even when sh is actually bash (for compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to use something as simple as `cut` to process fields in a CSV file. CSV files can have embedded commas inside fields, which will fool cut, causing your code to do the wrong thing.

Instead, use something designed specifically to process CSV files, such as Ruby's [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class. Something like this untested code will get you started:

```
require 'csv'

csv_file1 = CSV.open('file1')
csv_file2 = CSV.open('file2')

until (csv_file1.eof? || csv_file2.eof?) do
  row1 = csv_file1.shift
  row2 = csv_file2.shift

  # do something to diff the fields
  puts "#{ csv_file1.lineno }: #{ row1[1] } == #{ row2[2] } --> #{ row1[1] == row2[2] }"
end

[
  [csv_file1, 'file1'],
  [csv_file2, 'file2']
].each do |f, fn|
  puts "Hit EOF for #{ fn }" if f.eof?
  f.close
end
```